# How is structure the test so I dont use cy.wait(xx)

Tags: javascript, cypress

I have the following test.

1. Store value of A.
2. Change the value of A via API.
3. Store the New value of A.
4. Verify if A is equal to (A & New changes)

My test is working fine but when I fire the API the data isn't changed on the front end so I need to reload the page and wait for the element to load.

My test looks something like below.

```
                //API request
                cy.statusHold(79338)                    
                //Reload the page for changes to reflect on the front end
                cy.reload()   
                // Unless i don't use this wait it's unable to locate the below element.      
                cy.wait(5000)   
                cy.get(#locater)
```

Comment: Is it the element not loading after the reload or is data not updated after the reload?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can increase the amount of time Cypress waits for a condition to be true. What is most likely happening now is that after reloading, if the call hasn't been completed, then the actual data does not meet your expected, and the test failed.

```js
cy.statusHold(79338)
cy.reload()
cy.get(#locater, { timeout: 10000 }); // update timeout to 10s. Default is 4s
```

Comment: Thanks work perfectly fine but I am using a page object how do I include timeout part if my locater on test is.
`cy.statusHold(79338)
cy.reload()
page.object()`

Comment: I don't think I fully understand. if `page.object()` contains the `cy.get()` command, you'd have to modify it where the `.object()` function exists.